# Rolling Up Weeks to Quarter or Period. If the data satifies all weeks exist for that

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have financial data weekly basis from Week 1 to 52 0r 53. We have definition for Quarter and Periods.

Quarter Definition:
       Q1 Weeks 1-16
       Q2 Weeks 17-28
       Q3 Weeks 29-40
       Q4 Weeks 41-52/53

Period:
    Every 4 weeks is one period. It might be 13 or 14 periods depending on year.
Period  Week_Num
1   4
2   8
3   12
4   16
5   20
6   24
7   28
8   32
9   36
10  40
11  44
12  48
13  52

I need my data set to be rolled up to Quarter or Period, if current week covers whole quarter or period. 
One condition, Always last couple weeks should be shown. If only one week left, it needs to be broken into weeks.
I am looking for a better solution in SQL or in SSRS Report. Any help is appreciated. I need it as a funciton, so it can be used for all different data sets.
My Solution:
    SELECT FY_Quarter, MAX(FY_Week) As Week_Num INTO #Quarter
    FROM dimdate WHERE FY_Year =YEAR(getdate())     GROUP BY FY_Quarter

```
SELECT FY_Period, MAX(FY_Week) AS Week_Num INTO #Period
FROM dimdate WHERE FY_Year =YEAR(getdate()) GROUP BY FY_Period
```

Use these to join and roll up.

Here is the dataset

```
Current Data:
Weeks   Amount
Week 1  $15
Week 2  $15
Week 3  $15
Week 4  $15
Week 6  $15
Week 7  $15
Week 8  $15
Week 9  $15
Week 10 $15
Week 11 $15
Week 12 $15
Week 13 $15
Week 14 $15
Week 15 $15
Week 16 $15
Week 17 $15
Week 18 $15
Week 19 $15
Week 20 $15
Week 21 $15
```

New Data Set:

```
Weeks/Quarter/Period    Amount
Q1              $240
Week 17         $15
Week 18         $15
Week 19         $15
Week 20         $15
Week 21         $15
```

Comment: What is the statement you are using?

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using (MySQL, SQL-Server, PostgeSQL etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following for the quarters and weeks:

```
with PartQuarterData(week) as
(
select
    case
    when (select max(week) from FinancialData) < 16 then week
    when week > 16 and (select max(week) from FinancialData) < 28 then week
    when week > 28 and (select max(week) from FinancialData) < 40 then week
    when week > 40 and (select max(week) from FinancialData) < 53 then week
    else -1
    end
from FinancialData
)
select sum(amount) as Total,
    case
    when week >= 0 and week <= 16 then "Quarter 1"
    when week >= 17 and week <= 28 then "Quarter 2"
    when week >= 29 and week <= 40 then "Quarter 3"
    when week >= 41 and week <= 53 then "Quarter 4"
    end as "Weeks/Quarters"
from FinancialData
where week not in
(
select week
from PartQuarterData
)
group by
    case
    when week >= 0 and week <= 16 then "Quarter 1"
    when week >= 17 and week <= 28 then "Quarter 2"
    when week >= 29 and week <= 40 then "Quarter 3"
    when week >= 41 and week <= 53 then "Quarter 4"
    end
union all
select amount, "Week " + cast(week as varchar(2)) as "Weeks/Quarters"
from FinancialData
where week in
(
select week
from PartQuarterData
)
```

Comment: Consider a CTE or derived table to avoid repeating long `CASE` statement.

Comment: Thanks, it helps with this one. Now it has more complexity to it

Comment: @Gouda The query is built by adding logical building blocks, so it may look complex but it is easy to understand.

Comment: It works really good for ONLY Quarter, Now I need to do the Period and and Quarter.